# How to validate using conditional statement

Tags: citrus-framework

I designed a customized reporting template, I am wondering how to put the report block inside a conditional statement.

For Example:

If the Below code execute succesfullt and status is Failed, Then how to capture it inside my report.

```
    http()
        .client(todoClient1)
        .receive()
        .response(HttpStatus.OK)
        .validate("$.statusCode", "202");
```

Thanks In Advance
BJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom reporter should implement TestListener interface that is called with failed test state when something went wrong during the test. The failed state includes the failure stack trace as well as the exception cause. Also the listener is provided with test case object that provides the method `getLastExecutedAction()`. This is the last executed action that caused the failure.

Also the conditional block action provides direct access to the nested actions in the conditional container for detailed customized reporting then.

Comment: HI Chris, I have implemented the Extent Report API, Its gel well with Citrus, But However the failed report contains the complete Stack Trace, Is there a Method to only add the Failed Message.

Comment: This is My Extent API call (ETest.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "TEST FAILED ",cause ); ->

Comment: I got the Answer Chris, Its cause.toString(). Thanks Much for all the Help